# Want to accept "all changes" in a MS Word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I do know there is an "accept all changes" tab, but I can't find it. I have an MS WORD document with changes tracked by "highlight all changes". Now I want to accept all of them, but can't find where

Answer (score 0):

No idea what version you are using, but:

Review Tab > Accept Button > Accept All Changes